# android:launchMode singleInstance Questions

Tags: android, launchmode

Android's singleInstance launchMode seems to do what I want for the main tasks of my application, which is to keep the state of that Activity whenever I navigate back to it from a left menu bar.

The problem is, with this launchMode set, I see a horrible black flicker between activities on most devices.  A Google search didn't turn up anything as to whether this is normal, or how to fix it.

I tried singleTask, but that doesn't do what I would like exactly, since if I go from task A - B - C, then back to A, task B is removed from the stack and its state must be reloaded again when I start that Activity.

Also, and this may be a lack of fully understanding singleInstance, but the back button no longer works for those Activities.  What I would like to happen is that any singleInstance activity goes back to the home screen when the back button is pressed.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried overriding your transition animation?

Here is some of my code that I use for that:

```
   public void goToNextScreen(View v) {


        if (savedCueCardActivity == null) {
            savedCueCardActivity = new Intent().setClass(this, CueCardActivity.class);
            startActivity(savedCueCardActivity);
            //       lastActivity.finish();
        } else {
            savedCueCardActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(savedCueCardActivity);
        }
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }
```

Comment: Is there a way to retain the state of an activity that is singleTask, without popping the whole task off the stack if I go back to another singleTask activity?

Comment: I prefer to not use the singleTask method and just keep a reference to my activity in my mainActivity.  I just like the control.  Then I just call startActivity on my saved activity.